# Magento 1.7 - Debug isAvailable

Tags: magento, product

I have a multistore with some strange issue:
In one shop $product->isAvailable() returns true on some products, but on the other shop $product->isAvailable() always returns null.

In this function isAvailable()

```
$this->getTypeInstance(true)->isSalable($this)
```

and

```
Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
```

both return null.
Both products have the same attributes, and the general store configuration concerning stock availability is used for both shops.

Before upgrading i used v.1.4.0.2 and i suppose the logic of isAvailable()/isSaleable() has changed a little bit.
I don't get the difference of these two products which is the reason for one product not being avaliable.

**//EDIT :**

After some debugging i found out that the method

```
isSalable($product = null)
```

called by $this->getTypeInstance(true)->isSalable($this) in isAvailable() returns 0 because

```
$this->getProduct($product)->getData('is_salable')
```

is 0. This leads to the question which attributes are in charge of this generated is_saleable attribute.

Comment: The function shouldn't be isSaleable() ? It's what I have. Sale able = able to sale

Comment: the function isSalable() is defined in Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract in line 294

Answer (score 1):

You could try the solution mentioned [here](http://www.dconstructing.com/2011/12/14/magento-products-is_salable-attribute-from-the-admin)

Essentially it involves switching to the default store before you call isSaleable() or isAvailable().

```
$originalStore = Mage::app()->getStore(); // save the original store setting
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('default'); //switch to the default store
        $productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
            if (!$product->isSalable()) {
                // Do what you gotta do
            }
        }
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($originalStore->getId()); // switch back to the original
    }
```